# What does the participation tab on the users page on the meta site mean?

Tags: support, user-interface

I was checking out the users page on the meta site (I know, must have been really board) and this is what I saw:

[image: Participation tab on the users page on the meta site]

Does this mean I have the most participation on meta than anybody? That can't be right. Does it mean that I have the most meta participation within a certain time frame? I can buy that, but what time frame? I don't understand what the tab is supposed to tell me.

Comment: -1 This question reflects lack of research and as Ward pointed out, lack of hovering.  It may be a better fit in meta.stackexchange.com instead of meta.christianity.stackexachange.com due to the scope - where it would be flagged as a duplicate.  With that said, congratulations on being #1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is covered on Meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145151/how-is-meta-participation-calculated)

Copy/paste answer below:

---

This is pretty much answered by the tooltip you get when you hover over the "participation" sort link:

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

-- that's all it is. Take the sum of those four values and sort the users based on those sums. The only minor details that are not in the tooltip are things like "don't count deleted stuff", and the fact that "votes" includes answer acceptance and that "edits" excludes edits to your own posts.

Comment: There's a tooltip if you hover over the Participation link that shows the same meaning.

Comment: Sometimes I move so fast that the tooltip doesn't even have time to pop up. Thanks for the quick and succinct answer.